# TypeScript - prevent imported JSON file from getting cached

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

So this is my problem:
I need to import a JSON file into a TypeScript class. I can just do this with:

```
import * as data from 'data.json';
```

Which works fine. Only the JSON file is changing. And when I import it like this, it caches the JSON file and won't show the changes accurately.

I've googled this and only found solutions that involve Ajax calls, node fs or node file-loader. None of these are possible with my setup.

So does anyone know of a way how to re-import JSON files? It doesn't even have to be when they change, but maybe on some click event or so. Or prevent caching from imports in the first place.

Also, I am using webpack...

Comment: Why do you think `import` works but reading the file normally (using `fs`) doesn't?

Comment: Please elaborate why `fs.readFile()` is not possible in your setup?

Comment: What is this app? Is this a web application, a node app - server or cli?